# How to specify the path of index.html in Rollup config for Svelte

Tags: svelte, rollup, rollupjs

I am using the default Rollup config as my bundler for Svelte, but I want to use a different path for the bundle files and index.html

I can successfully change the path for the bundle files with this:

```js
export default {
  input: "src/main.ts",
  output: {
    sourcemap: true,
    format: "iife",
    name: "app",
    file: "../static/build/bundle.js",
},
```

But it still looks for the `index.html` file in the original path. I would like to add that into the `static` folder as well, just like the build files.

How can I configure rollup to specify the path of the single `index.html` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [sveltejs/template](https://github.com/sveltejs/template) the build config does not deal with the html file, you can simply manually move it to where you want it to be. That said, you could use the [copy plugin for rollup](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-copy) to copy files during build.